# geopandas read shp file with fiona.errors.DriverError when wrapping up as a package

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas, setup.py, fiona

I have a package structure like this:

```
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── main
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── application.py
│   ├── core_function
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── maps
│   │       ├── Taiwan
│   │       ├── Taiwan_detailed
│   │       └── taiwan.txt
└── setup.py
```

I try to wrap this package by `python setup.py develop`.
When it runs `Taiwan = gpd.read_file(pkg_resources.resource_stream(__name__, 'maps/Taiwan/COUNTY_MOI_1090820.shp'))` in application.py,
`fiona.errors.DriverError: '/vsimem/9b633f8a8a3f457eadf710539afd2a22' not recognized as a supported file format.` or
`fiona._err.CPLE_OpenFailedError: '/vsimem/9b633f8a8a3f457eadf710539afd2a22' not recognized as a supported file format.` would occur.

It reads perfectly when I run it as a script on my machine, but it fails as a package.

Knowing that the shp file should be read along with all the files in that folder, in my setup.py I also include them

```
packages= setuptools.find_packages(),
package_data={'maps': ['main/core_function/maps/*','core_function/maps/Taiwan/*']},
```

I was thinking the problem is about the path, but taiwan.txt can be read.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So far I have not found the reason.
But I instead used the to_file method and work with only one file.
`.to_file("package.gpkg", driver="GPKG")`
This works in my package. The problem can be due to reading multiple files.